# Fungus or dust?

Tags: lens, dust, fungus

yesterday I noticed this spot on my zuiko 12-40mm lens, besides other dust particles (I hope it's dust).

[image]

[image]

[image]

It's a bit visible after f8. I shot with f22.

I checked the lens last week and it didn't had the spot, I noticed it when I shot at a blue background and I saw a pretty big spot on the right side of the frame.

It doesnt have snowflake or spiderweb pattern, it's just round and I can notice a little hole in the middle of the spot.

Another detail, I didn't had the spot, last week for example, it just came from nowhere, so I think its just dust but the size and the color... I can notice it only at higher fstops

I hope someone can help me with an answer, is it fungus or just dust?

---

Additional images:

Best I could do at this hour and my useless smartphone ^^

Had to post here so its more visible, sorry for not replying, I know its not hight quality but yeah, I try my luck.

Also I can see further in the lens, with the flash, more spots like that but more transparent.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you post the full permanent link to the images, we can turn them into inline images here so that people can view them all in one place. FYI.

Comment: Have you tried properly cleaning the rear lens element?

Answer (score 3):

Things on the back of a lens can cast shadows, but they have to be pretty big before they're noticeable. To see just how big, please take a look at Roger Cicala's lensrentals.com blog entry: [The Apocalypse of Lens Dust](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/08/the-apocalypse-of-lens-dust/)

[image]

Whatever is on the rear element of your lens is not the right size to cause what your example image is showing. That's almost certainly caused by dust on the front of the sensor stack.

> But it can be mold tho,im not concered about the image im concered about the mold

You'll need to post much higher quality (clearer and higher magnification) images for any of us to have any chance to tell what, exactly, it is or is not. To my eye it looks like it might be residue left behind by a water spot, but it is hard to tell from the images you have posted. Water spots are fairly easy to clean when using the [proper methods](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/49049/15871). Trying to remove them with dry cleaning cloths can scratch your lens coatings.

Comment: Just looked at the sensor and i see just small dust particles,but not something that is bigger than the others so what now...

Comment: But it can be mold tho,im not concered about the image im concered about the mold :D

Comment: @croco1 You'll need to post much higher quality (clearer and higher magnification) images for any of us to be able to tell what, exactly, it is or is not. To my eye it looks like it might be residue left behind by a water spot, but it is hard to tell from the images you have posted.

Answer (score 1):

The dust spots you see on the lens will not image, they are harmless. The spot you see in your image is due to dust on the cover glass of your camera's image sensor. Check your camera manual for best sensor cleaning practice.

Comment: thanks for the advice,but are you sure that big dust particle(i hope it's dust) it's harmless? I mean on the image you can see it's somehow looking like that white spot,cuz its pretty big.How could i get dust on the sensor and the rear lens at the same time,because i think i got it during a shooting yday while it was snowing.

Comment: I am positive -- dust on the lens only serves to block a minuscule amount of light from reaching film or digital sensor. Dust on the lens will increase the amount of stray light that enters. This stray light will reduce contrast but your image shows only minimal dust so the flare level will be about normal. For scientific purposes one can "dot" a lens with wax pencil to micro adjust image brightness. These dots will not image, try it your self if you are brave.