# Minolta MC Tele Rokkor-PE 200mm f4.5 Service Manual

Tags: repair, minolta

Do you have any copy or a link where I can find a service manual for Minolta MC Rokkor-PE 200mm f4.5? I recently bought this lens for $15 and in mint condition, but the front element has dust which a regular rocket blower couldn't rid and would like to properly clean it. I would be happy if anyone know also a good source for other Minolta MC lenses service manual.

Comment: Is the dust on the front surface of the lens? Or inside the lens? If inside, before you go about mucking up your lens by taking it apart, you might want to read Roger Cicala's excellent blog entry: [The Apocalypse of Lens Dust](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2011/08/the-apocalypse-of-lens-dust/)

Comment: On the front surface both the front and rear element. I can't access the rear element correctly while cleaning because its small and located deeply on to the body of the lens. So might want to remove the rear group element to clean the rear properly as well as the front element.

Comment: Like Roger (who founded what is almost certainly the company that owns the most lenses in the world not sitting on shelves in warehouses waiting to be sold) in the linked article above, I'd advise again taking apart a lens, particularly one with which you're not familiar or have no instructions to help you tell the difference between connecting screws that do not affect lens alignment and screws that do affect lens alignment. All lenses have dust in them, even before they leave the factory. It takes an awful LOT of dust before it begins to affect image quality to any perceivable degree.

Comment: For cleaning the externally accessible surfaces of lenses, please see: [Cleaning stains left by frost from the front of a lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/49049/15871)